# django url rewrite without redirect

Tags: django, apache, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm using django and have hundreds of subdomain url

```
abc.domain.com
```

want to rewrite to

```
domain.com/site/abc/
```

Is it possible via url-rewriting that the user won't see

```
domain.com/site/abc/
```

in his browser, but sees

```
abc.domain.com
```

This can be done at apache side. But my question is, can we do it inside django?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks more like a name registrant thing, point the subdomain `abc.domain.com` to `yourIp/site/abc`, is it what you want?

Comment: I have hundreds of xxx.domain.com, it may not easy to manually setup subdomains. so I want to know can we do it with django.

Comment: Why don't you just host the site at `abc.domain.com`? Does the site also need to be accessible from `domain.com/site/abc/`?

Comment: I have hundreds of xxx.domain.com. It's natural to use domain.com/site/abc/ as a Django url to display pages. It doesn't need  to be accessible from the domain.com/site/abc/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand you question, but maybe some fiddling with request.urlconf and custom middleware is the solution? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.urlconf

Answer (score 0):

The Django sites framework does provide some tools to deal with multiple domains, but they all assume you have a different SITE_ID for each deployment.

That said. You can probably write up a middleware that checks `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` and then passes that information off to your view in whatever way you wish.

At that point you can just follow the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/?from=olddocs#the-currentsitemanager) on using a site custom manager for your models.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run apache, I think this kind of request can be handle via APACHE's rewrite engine